# Django remove bulk-delete

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is a very simple question: **Is there any good way to disable calling a bulk-delete (through querysets of course) on all models in an entire Django project?**

The reasoning for this is under the premise that **completely** deleting data is almost always a poor choice, and an accidental bulk-delete can be detrimental.

Comment: I'm guessing this would involve subclassing `QuerySet` and changing the `delete` method to your liking, subclassing the default manager and have it use your custom query set, subclassing model - create an abstract model and have it use your custom manager and then finally have all your models subclass your custom abstract model.

Comment: Elssar's approach is what I'd do generally speaking. Another approach to consider if you are dealing with an existing code base and/or can't be certain all models will derive from your custom abstract model is to monkey patch QuerySet's delete method as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like comments says on your first post, you have to create a subclass for each of these elements:

1. The model manager
2. Queryset class
3. BaseModel

After some search, [a great example can be found here](http://datahackermd.com/2013/django-soft-deletion/), all credits to Akshay Shah, the blog author. Before looking to the code, be aware of that:

> *However, it inevitably leads to data corruption.* The problem is simple: using a Boolean to store deletion status makes it impossible to enforce uniqueness constraints in your database.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet


class SoftDeletionQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        # Bulk delete bypasses individual objects' delete methods.
        return super(SoftDeletionQuerySet, self).update(alive=False)

    def hard_delete(self):
        return super(SoftDeletionQuerySet, self).delete()

    def alive(self):
        return self.filter(alive=True)

    def dead(self):
        return self.exclude(alive=True)


class SoftDeletionManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive_only = kwargs.pop('alive_only', True)
        super(SoftDeletionManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.alive_only:
            return SoftDeletionQuerySet(self.model).filter(alive=True)
        return SoftDeletionQuerySet(self.model)

    def hard_delete(self):
        return self.get_queryset().hard_delete()


class SoftDeletionModel(models.Model):
    alive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = SoftDeletionManager()
    all_objects = SoftDeletionManager(alive_only=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self):
        self.alive = False
        self.save()

    def hard_delete(self):
        super(SoftDeletionModel, self).delete()
```

Basically, it adds an `alive` field to check if the row has been deleted or not, and update it when the `delete()` method is called.
Of course, this method works only on project where you can manipulate the code base.

Answer (score 1):

There are nice off-the-shelf applications that allow for restoring deleted models (if that is what you are interested in), here are ones I used:

- Django softdelete: https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete I used it more
- Django reversion: https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion this one is updated more often, and allows you to revert to any version of your model (not only after delete, but as well after update).

If you really want to forbid bulk deletes, I'd discourage you from this approach as it will:

- Break expectations about applicaiton behaviour. If I call `MyModel.objects.all().delete()` I want table to be empty afterwards.
- Break existing applications.

If you want do do it please follow advice from comment:

> I'm guessing this would involve subclassing QuerySet and changing the delete method to your liking, subclassing the default manager and have it use your custom query set, subclassing model - create an abstract model and have it use your custom manager and then finally have all your models subclass your custom abstract model.